# Click events stop working after firing once backbone js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a number of click events that link to different places on my site as well as pages off my site.

It seems the first time I click on one, it works initially, but after that ALL my click events stop firing completely.

Not sure what's going on, and what code I should post?

I am using a router to render a number of views on the site.

I should also mention that my console does not show any errors.

Here is where the scripts are called. The ids for the click events have been edited, but i have checked and are all correct (click works on first go so they would be anyway).

**EDIT Important note:** It seems that click events are fine UNTIL navigation occurs

```
<!--templates-->
<!--Home -->
<script type="template/jquery" id="home_template">
    <%= partial "templates/home_template" %>
</script>
<!--Portfolio -->
<script type="template/jquery" id="portfolio_template">
    <%= partial "templates/portfolio_template" %>
</script>
<!--About-->
<script type="template/jquery" id="about_template">
    <%= partial "templates/about_template" %>
</script>



<!--Javascripts-->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/backfire/0.3.0/backbone-firebase.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/modernizr.js"></script>
<!--Application-->
<script src="javascripts/models.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/views.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/routes.js"></script>
<!--script src="javascripts/application.js"></script-->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //home links
        $("#recent_work").click(function() {
           router.navigate("portfolio", true)
        });            

        //portfolio links
        $("#xx").click(function() {
            window.open('http://chexxxxxs.com.au/');
        });

        $("#xx").click(function() {
            window.open('http://updaxxxxxal.com.au/');
        });

        $("#xx").click(function() {
            window.open('http://whxxxxnry.com.au/');
        });

        $("#xx").click(function() {
            window.open('http://frexxxxxe.com.au/');
        });

        $("#xx").click(function() {
            window.open('http://puxxxxxel.com/');
        });

        $("#xx").click(function() {
            window.open('http://xxxxxxing.com.au/');
        });

    });
</script>
```

Routes file:

```
 var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
  '': 'home',
  'home' : 'home',
  'portfolio' : 'portfolio',
  'about' : 'about'
}
});

var homeView = new HomeView({ el: $("#container") });
var portfolioView = new PortfolioView({ el: $("#container") });
var aboutView = new AboutView({ el: $("#container") });

var router = new Router();

router.on('route:home', function () {
    homeView.render();
});

router.on('route:portfolio', function () {
    portfolioView.render();
});

router.on('route:about', function () {
    aboutView.render();
});

Backbone.history.start();
```

views:

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render : function () {
        var template = _.template( $("#home_template").html(), {} );
        this.$el.html(template);
    }
});

var PortfolioView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render : function () {
        var template = _.template( $("#portfolio_template").html(), {} );
        this.$el.html(template);
    }
});

var AboutView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render : function () {
        var template = _.template( $("#about_template").html(), {} );
        this.$el.html(template);
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the console? This happens when there is an error somewhere in your code. And shouldn't we see the code?

Comment: yes no errors, the code is quite long and accorss multiple scripts, not sure which part of the code is most relevant?

Comment: If there is no errors, there should be something logically incorrect. Posting the error-prone part should be sufficient? Your question as it doesn't show the problem.

Comment: Added what I think could be relevant

Comment: Thanks, surely the IDs are unique? Note that if you are creating the elements dynamically you should delegate the events. If they belong to a Backbone View, you can use it's `events` option, which delegates the events for you.

Comment: yes, all unique, and there shouldnt be any problem with them because they work fine individually

Comment: ah okay this could be the problem, as its only on navigation the click events stop working, how can I do this? is there any example?

Comment: Please check this http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents

Comment: okay so I need to define the events within the view? `events: `

Comment: If the `a` elements are descendants of your View, yes. Otherwise delegate the events from document object or another element, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on

Comment: ok, sorry but what do the `a` elements have to do with it?

Comment: do you mean the elements that will function as links? not actual a elements?

Comment: Actually type of the element doesn't matter. I thought the `#xx` elements are anchors. Sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: no problem will give it a go and report back

Comment: Hey @undefined, I got it fixed thanks to your advice so thank you, did you want to add an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: You are very welcome, glad to be of help, I think you can answer the question better than me, please answer your own question, accept it, and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to @undefined for help coming up with this answer.

When my views are rendered the container is emptied out with `.html()` this leads to an unbinding of the events. In backbone the events within a view have to be defined in the view itself in the "events" hash, when you do this backbone automatically re delegates the events.

```
var PortfolioView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render : function () {
        var template = _.template( $("#portfolio_template").html(), {} );
        this.$el.html(template);
    },
    events: {
        "click .portfolio_item" : "linktoLive"
    },
    linktoLive: function (e) {
        var link = $(e.currentTarget).attr("data-link");
        window.open(link);
    }
});
```

Under the events hash, add events in this format `event binding : function to execute on event` then add the function after.